# Timer Inside Label

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to put a countdown timer insde my label in my program, but when I run the program it doesn't countdown. It skips right to one, and that's it.

```
Private Sub CompactTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CompactTimer.Tick
    Dim Time As Integer = 11
    Do Until Time = 0
        ClockLabel.Text = "Compacting database in: " & Time
        Time -= 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

I also have started the timer and declared the interval to 500 in the Form_Load routuine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the loop and declare the Time variable outside the scope.

```
Dim Time As Integer = 11

Private Sub CompactTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                              Handles CompactTimer.Tick
  If Time >= 0 Then
    ClockLabel.Text = "Compacting database in: " & Time
    Time -= 1
  Else
    CompactTimer.Stop
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hahah well that made me feel dumb, thank you. I cannot accept an answer for another 9 mintues but i will when I can.

Answer (score 3):

make a static var ..

```
Private Sub CompactTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CompactTimer.Tick
    Static Time As Integer = 11

    ClockLabel.Text = "Compacting database in: " & Time
    Time -= 1
    If Time = 0 Then CompactTimer.Stop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop happens each time the timer ticks.  You most likely want something like:

```
Dim time as Integer = 11 ' Declare outside
Private Sub CompactTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CompactTimer.Tick
    If Time = 0 Then
        CompactTimer.Enabled = False ' Disable timer
        ClockLabel.Text = "Compacting database now"
    Else
        ClockLabel.Text = "Compacting database in: " & time
        time -= 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the code to show the actual amount of time then the code could look like this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'start the count down
    CompactTimer.Interval = 500
    CompactTimer.Start()
    stpw.Stop()
    stpw.Reset()
    stpw.Restart()
End Sub

Dim stpw As New Stopwatch
Dim countdown As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 11) 'length of countdown in seconds

Private Sub CompactTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CompactTimer.Tick
    Dim togo As TimeSpan = countdown - stpw.Elapsed
    If togo.TotalSeconds > 0 Then
        ClockLabel.Text = String.Format("Compacting database in: {0} secs.", togo.TotalSeconds.ToString("n0"))
    Else
        CompactTimer.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Relying on the interval to mark the passing of time will result in inaccuracy.